# Need help in building Android version of javax.sampled. AudioInputStream

Tags: java, android, wav, javasound

Since Android doesnt support javax.sampled sound apis am trying to build AudioInputStream and Audioformat for WAV FILE. I tried to build a WAVE FILE class by reading the WAV file using this https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ 
And using this wave object i tried to create my own AudioInputStream .. But it is not working . Any help is highly appreciated ? Does AudioInputstream contains only PCM data or what ?

Comment: Are you wanting to play the wav file? If so just used MediaPlayer.

Comment: I am writing voice biometrics for Android ..

Answer (score 1):

> Does AudioInputstream contains only PCM data or what ?

No, it can contain various types.

Comment: Android doesnt support Audiosystem,AudioInputstream,Audiofileformat and AudioFormat ... So am writing it myself .. What I meant was Does AudioInputStream  contains Just Audio data (could be PCM or any other) Or Only Audiodata along with the header ?

Comment: See edit to answer.  It contains no more, or different information, in fact less - but you seemed to have trouble with my earlier version, so I took that part out.  Maybe my answer should just be *"Or what."*.

Comment: Alright .. What does the parameter **bold** private InputStream  stream; Inside AudioInputStream hold ? **bold** Does it start with Audio data directly or with the header ?

Comment: ?!?  Are you referring to [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#AudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20long%29)?  If not, I have no idea what your are asking.

Comment: Ok here is what iam doing . I have the WAV file being read and stored in Inputstream .Now i am adding this information to the Audioinputstream with constructor. I am confused as to do i have to just send data only or the Data with header.I tried both but it is not working :( i must be doign some thign wrong . I am clueless . any help is appreciated ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it ... AudioInputStream chops off the first 14 bytes of Audio data and updates the length correspondingly . Hence I was  able to see the difference ..